# Options for "create and reference"

Tags: 7, nodes

In a [screencast](http://www.vimeo.com/21686630) based on Drupal 6, I spotted (~3:45) that several fields had an additional "create and reference" icon that would pop a secondary dialog, for in-place creation of non-existent nodes, which would then be added as reference. This appears to be missing from Drupal 7 [Reference](http://drupal.org/project/references) module, which is now responsible for fields of that type, and I can't seem to find any evidence it's going to be put back.

My homework:
I dug up an old groups.drupal thread where eventually someone posted a [round-up](http://groups.drupal.org/node/13162#comment-233573) of many options last year, but most of those now range from inactive to abandoned. A few have issue threads full of people asking about a Drupal 7 upgrade, with absolute silence from the maintainers.
From that list, two actually show Drupal 7 work:

1. [Node Reference Create](http://drupal.org/project/noderefcreate): Seems to only do the barest minimum: create a node with a title of what you input in the textarea. To provide values for any other fields, you need to make your way over to that node's individual edit screen. This isn't enough for my needs.
2. [Corresponding node references](http://drupal.org/project/cnr): I'm actually just not sure why this is even on the list. I've installed it, poked around, and can't actually find this feature implemented. Am I just missing it?

I'm also aware of [Relation](http://drupal.org/project/relation), which seems intended to supersede just about every other reference-ish module and I presume will do this. But it doesn't even have any released code at the moment, and this research is for something I'm working on right now, timeline of probably a couple months tops.

Are there any *currently* viable options for accomplishing this? I'm willing to guinea pig anything at least in beta status. Or do I need to give serious consideration to doing this in Drupal 6 instead?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the overlay module in Drupal 7. Create the main node but use the Node Reference URL widget on the referencing nodes. This will put links on every node view page that behave similar to the Relationships module. If you add [Field Collections module](http://drupal.org/project/field_collection) to group all the fields, you can get edit in place with overlay popups on the node.

The workflow would be like this. 1. Create a node. 2. The node form only asks for the title of the node. 3. Return to the node with several different parts, each getting their own popup form or if JavaScript is enabled a return destination back to the node after creating or editing.

Comment: This actually looks promising; thanks. Will have to do a bit of experimenting.

Comment: If you log into [this site](http://urbo.ro/local/hard-rock-cafe-85057), you can see the menu on the side of the information in the node to add a review, image or video. (You might need Google Chrome to translate for you.) This is done through the NR URL widget. Notice how the reviews are nodes added like comments through a View? Where have I seen comments with comments?Thinking like that can lead to some cool stuff in Drupal.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't have a Drupal 7 release, so far, but the [Node Relationships](http://drupal.org/project/noderelationships) module to is the module for this feature, on Drupal 6.

> The Node Relationships module provides methods to complete two way relationships between content types enhancing the features of node reference fields.
>
> Almost all the settings to administer the features of this module can be located at Administer -> Content management -> Content types -> [type] -> Relationships.

Answer (score 0):

While waiting for a solution to mature, I've just been adding field help descriptions to nodereferences such as 'Choose a foo or add a new foo.'