# How to create node and reference it in Drupal 7?

Tags: nodes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Options for “create and reference”](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/1979/options-for-create-and-reference)

How can I put a link "Add another item" on a node edit page that would create a new node and reference it at the same parent node ?

Also, I need to put Edit link beside the new created & referenced node.

I found modules like the [Popups API](http://drupal.org/project/popups) and [Popups: Add and Reference](http://drupal.org/project/popups_reference), but, sadly they are not ported to D7

Thanks for any hints!

Comment: This should be migrated to Drupal Answers

Answer (score 2):

http://drupal.org/project/noderefcreate

This one is available for D7, and allows you to create & reference nodes within the create / edit form for another node type. Unlike the popups_reference module, it will only allow you to create the extra nodes with titles (no other fields). You could, however, use this and then write a small custom module that uses `hook_form_alter()` to redirect the user to the edit forms for newly-created nodes to enter the rest of the information.

Not as nice as popups_reference, but it should work.

Comment: I need to create & reference a new child node type without leaving the parent node edit page, please read my comments to M.Reda below.

Comment: I think that the noderefcreate module referenced above will do most of what you need. If you just go into Views, you can display the newly-created Chapters with edit links somewhere on the course page (probably using a block). I think that should do it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what are you trying to do, Samir.
Have you tried Node Reference URL Widget (http://drupal.org/project/nodereference_url)

If it's not the right one, explain a bit more what are you trying to do.

Comment: Thanks M.Reda,

What I am trying to do is to create a course building website,
I have created three content types, Course, Chapter& Page

In the Course edit page, I need to add a link "Add new chapter", pressing this link will create and reference a new Chapter content type without leaving the Course edit page, then a new link to the newly created chapter get visible at the bottom of page, which if pressed will navigate to the chapter edit page.

I will need to apply the same thing for adding pages to a chapter.

Please advice, I really appreciate your response.